# ODBC Source Editor Preview Disappeared

Tags: ssis

Usually when I use SSIS I can preview data from my ODBC Source Editor. This has disappeared for me, does anyone know how I can reenable this at all?

I have added the ODBC connection manager (blanked out the name for the purposes of posting online as this isn't relevant), refreshed all of my connection details but this hasn't made any difference.

Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks!

Please see below for a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Restarting Visual Studio or SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) can sometimes resolve temporary glitches or configuration issues. Close the application and reopen it to see if the problem persists.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me Amira. I've restarted the application a few times, including ending it from task manager, but this hasn't resolved my issue

Comment: Sometimes, an outdated or incompatible driver can cause issues with the data preview functionality. Verify that you have the latest version of the driver installed.